# How to setup UEFI support on Serva?

Tags: windows-8.1, pxe

I'm trying to setup a PXE server with [Serva](https://www.vercot.com/%7Eserva/) to deploy Windows 8.1 for a bunch of HP ElitePads. The server is working correctly for other PCs and virtual machines, but not the the HP ElitePads.

I've read some articles which suggest the PXE server needs UEFI support to work with this model, but no documentation on the subject from Serva.

Is there a way to setup UEFI support on Serva? Are there any similar options to work around this without falling to Windows server?

Comment: The elitepads have UEFI. I need to change something serverside to get this tablets to recognize the boot options that are already working correctly on non-uefi systems.

Comment: What did you read exactly?

Comment: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-HP-ProBook-EliteBook/HP-Elitepad-900-PXE-boot-problem/td-p/6057507#.U3Y5y7mKAy8 This is my exact problem. It's probably the same issue.

Comment: You don't indicate which version of Windows Server your using.  It seems the solution is specific.  The server hardware must itself support EFI and also be running Windows Server 2012.

Comment: I'm not using any version of Windows server, im using Serva, not WDS to deploy. I want to know if it's posible for serva to be UEFI aware, and/or posible workarounds that don't involve a Windows server license to support one especific model

Answer (score 1):

Serva 2.x uses a `syslinux` derivative bootmanager which is a BIOS mode NBP (legacy). Serva 3.x will natively support UEFI.

Meanwhile you can set your UEFI PCs in "Legacy" mode and still use Serva 2.x

UPDATE: Serva 3.0 now supports UEFI.

Comment: The first answer was kind of inaccurate. First of all, Serva, which can be found at http://www.vercot.com/~serva/download.html only has Serva 2.x and 3.x don't seemed to exist. Unless 3.x is still being or under development. The only way to get UEFI WDS is by Windows 2012 Server in at least Stand Alone mode. Just like the rest of the other user, I am looking for something portable and does not require Server OS.

Comment: The answer is correct --Serva 3.x "will" natively support UEFI.--" it is not published yet.